# Postgresql- theowing an error running a basic query

Tags: postgresql, data-analysis

i am trying to run a query from a dataset but its throwing an error, please help me out.

```
select * from online_retail
where quantity= '6'
```

ERROR:

```
 column "quantity" does not exist
LINE 2: where quantity= '6'
              ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "online_retail.Quantity". 

SQL state: 42703

select * from online_retail
where quantity= '6'
```

i am epxecting result where quantity is 6

Comment: Did you create it with uppercase Q and double quotes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive

Comment: with uppercase Q, but isnt postgresql is case insensitive ? so it shouldnt matter, right ?

Comment: It's explained in the linked question. If you use double quotes to create the identifier you are telling PostgreSQL that case matters: https://dbfiddle.uk/TZH_DKHN - This behaviour is inherited from Oracle, an engine that heavily influences PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the message is obvious. A column named quantity does not exist. Probably you meant to write:

```
select * from online_retail where  online_retail."Quantity"= '6';
```

Or:

```
select * from online_retail where  "Quantity"= '6';
```

In postgreSQL, if you create your table using double quoted identifiers like "Quantity" then you need to refer that column as "Quantity" and writing quantity would not work. With quotes it also keeps the casing.

Comment: This `select * from online_retail where  "online_retail.Quantity"= '6';` will not work as you are using the error message Hint without actually testing it.  Your example turns the `table_name.column_name` into a column name of `"table_name.column_name"`. What would work is `select * from online_retail where  "online_retail"."Quantity"= '6';` or `select * from online_retail where  online_retail."Quantity"= '6';`. The important part is the column name.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver you are right first one was a typo. Correcting.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer.
but i dint put any inverted commas in quantity. other of my databases are working fine without " " this.

Comment: @PankajKatoch, I did not say inverted commas anywhere. It is double quotes. PostgreSQL works that way. Check your table's definition.

Comment: @CetinBasoz inverted commas are also called qoutation marks, single or double. 
how do i check my table's definition.??
you mean in the properties ??

Comment: @PankajKatoch, I don't know the tool you are using. Most of them show the table definition when you select the table in their explorer and\or you ask for table creation script. You might also do a select to get and idea of the column names.

Comment: @CetinBasoz i am using pgaadmin 4

Comment: @PankajKatoch, at left there is a tree. In that expand the nodes and find your table. Then click on "SQL" tab on right. You would see your table's definition as "Create table ..."

Comment: @PankajKatoch, BTW if it is safe for you to do so, you can rename that column: Alter Table yourTableName rename column "Quantity" to quantity;